# Different output with equal input for python program when using iminuit: undefined behavior?

Tags: python, pandas, iminuit

I encountered this wiered bugs that the iminuit cannot converge on a naive linear model. However, the real problem is, if I uncomment the line "#bins = np.linspace(0,4,25)", the result of the program is different, and it can converge.

If "same input" does not produce "same output", it means there is undefined behavior, or segmentation fault. Any ideas?

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.special
import probfit
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_feather('test.feather').rho2.to_numpy()
print(data)
N,bins = np.histogram(data,bins=24,range=(0,4))
#bins = np.linspace(0,4,25)
print(bins)
x = (bins[:-1]+bins[1:])/2

exposure = 3.8061025098100147
def cost(y0,k):
    global x,exposure,N
    T = (y0+k*x)*exposure
    return -2*np.sum(N*np.log(T)-T-sp.special.loggamma(N+1))

import iminuit
minimizer = iminuit.Minuit(cost,errordef=1,y0=11,k=3,limit_y0=(0,None),limit_k=(0.1,None))
minimizer.migrad()
minimizer.hesse()
minimizer.minos()
display(minimizer.fmin, minimizer.params,minimizer.merrors)
minimizer.draw_mncontour("y0","k")
```

output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beBK1.png)

Test input

[test.feather.zip](https://github.com/scikit-hep/iminuit/files/5086372/test.feather.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is solved. Although it **looks** the same using `print`, the types are different:

```py
data = pd.read_feather('test.feather').rho2.to_numpy()
N,bins = np.histogram(data,bins=24,range=(0,4))
```

vs

```py
bins = np.linspace(0,4,25)
```

The first returns `float32`, and the second returns `float64`. The `iminuit` need to calculate the gradient with numerical methods, so the precision of output of `cost` funciton need to be at least `float64`.

Best solution is

```
data = pd.read_feather('test.feather').rho2.to_numpy().astype('float64')
```